# Flex 4 - Dragging from list - dragsource.dataForFormat("itemsByIndex") is null

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, drag-and-drop

Thanks in advance for anyone who tries to help me out,

I am working with Flex 4 and am trying to get Drag and Drop working between Lists and between a List and non-list component.

I have a custom itemRenderer which has an image and a label.

Graphically everything works great but the data that is attached to the item I am dragging comes up in dragSource as null every time.

Here is my code:

```
    <s:List dataProvider="{userInventory}" itemRenderer="renderers.InventoryItemRenderer" width="198" height="294" y="34" dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true"  >
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout />        
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>

</s:BorderContainer>
<!-- /User Inventory -->
<s:BorderContainer dragEnter="fndragEnterHandler(event);" 
                   dragOver="fndragOverHandler(event);"
                   dragDrop="fndragDropHandler(event);" includeIn="crib" x="243" y="206" width="200" height="200">
    <s:Label x="10" y="10" text="This is supposed to be a baby" width="178" height="24"/>
    <s:Label x="10" y="39" text="State:" width="42" height="19"/>
    <s:Label x="59" y="37" width="80" height="24" id="baby_state"/>

</s:BorderContainer>
private function fndragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {

                DragManager.acceptDragDrop(IUIComponent(event.currentTarget));  
        }
        private function fndragOverHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {

                DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.MOVE);
        }

        private function dragOverCopyHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
            event.preventDefault();
            //if (event.dragSource.hasFormat("itemsByIndex"))
                DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.COPY);
        }

        private function fndragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {
            //event.preventDefault();

            monsterDebugger.trace(this, event.dragSource, null, "DRAG DROP");


            var items:Vector = event.dragSource.dataForFormat("itemsByIndex") as Vector;
            var baby:Array = babyObject.source;

            monsterDebugger.trace(this, items, null, "DRAG DROP");

            items[0].baby_id = baby[0]['Baby']['id'];

            var item:Object = new Object();

            item.id = items[0].id;
            item.baby_id = items[0].baby_id;
            item.effect = JSON.decode(items[0].effect);


            sendAction(item, "baby", userFbData.id, "use_item_on_baby");



            //TextInput(event.currentTarget).text=itemsArray[0].label;
        }
```

And here is my itemRenderer:

```
<mx:Image x="14" y="19" source="{data.image}" width="50" height="50" smoothBitmapContent="true"/>
<s:Label x="0" y="-1" text="{data.name}" fontFamily="Verdana" fontSize="12" color="#696565" width="80" height="21"/>
```

The items Vector in the drop handler comes back null every time and I can't quite figure out why.

I thought at first that it was because that particular case is not dragging from List to List, but I tried it that way also and the dragSource.dataForFormat("itemsByIndex") continues to return null.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it, I've been banging my head against this for two days!

Answer (score 0):

you cast to Vector may already nullify the dragsource data. so try with

```
var items:* = event.dragSource.dataForFormat("itemsByIndex");
```

Comment: Answer of Mihn Tran is not the answer. I have the same problem. But it only occurs when the list has scrollbars. Without them it works just fine. Definitely a bug in s:List.